# How to convince Coq this dependent pattern match is exhaustive?

Tags: coq

The stack definition and a test function to work with it are given below. The code works (when compiling example you will see an error, it is my problem).

```ml
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import List.ListNotations.

Inductive type1 : Set :=
| Unit1 : type1
| Timestamp1 : type1
| Option1 : type1 -> type1.

Inductive type2 : type1 -> Set :=
| Unit2 : type2 Unit1
| Timestamp2 : type2 Timestamp1
| Option2 {t} :
    type2 t -> type2 (Option1 t).

Definition stack_t := list type1.

Inductive stack : stack_t -> Set :=
| Head {t ts} :
  type2 t ->
  stack ts ->
  stack (t :: ts)
| Empty :
  stack [].

Record stacks (s1 : stack_t) : Set := Build {
  st1 : stack s1;                                             
}.

Definition test2 {ts_inp} (st_inp : stack ts_inp) : option (stacks ts_inp) :=
  match st_inp in stack ts_inp_cp1 with
  | @Head
      Timestamp1 ((Timestamp1 :: t_rest) as t_xrest)
      Timestamp2 (@Head Timestamp1 t_rest' Timestamp2 rest as xrest) =>
      match
        xrest
        in
        stack t_xrest
        return
        stack (Timestamp1 :: t_rest) -> option (stacks (Timestamp1 :: Timestamp1 :: t_rest))
      with
      | _ => fun '(Head Timestamp2 rest) => None
      end xrest
  | _ => None
  end.
```

System complains about `Non exhaustive pattern-matching`*.
**So, how to convince coq that this pattern matching is exhaustive?**

---

Some more explanations.

1. Another way to ask this question is : **how to convince the coq that `rest` has type `t_rest` (below)?** Right now coq 'thinks' that `rest` has type `t_rest'` as far as I can see from the error message. (Meaning that answer produces most likely the same result *for me*).

```ml
Definition test {ts_inp} (st_inp : stack ts_inp) : option (stacks ts_inp) :=
  match st_inp in stack ts_inp_cp1 with
  | @Head
      Timestamp1 (Timestamp1 :: t_rest)
      Timestamp2 (@Head Timestamp1 t_rest' Timestamp2 rest) =>
      Some (Build _ (Head Timestamp2 (Head Timestamp2 rest)))
  | _ => None
  end.
```

2. This particular case can be solved by given an alias to internal stack

```ml
Definition test1 {ts_inp} (st_inp : stack ts_inp) : option (stacks ts_inp) :=
  match st_inp in stack ts_inp_cp1 with
  | @Head
      Timestamp1 (Timestamp1 :: t_rest)
      Timestamp2 (@Head Timestamp1 t_rest' Timestamp2 rest as st) =>
      Some (Build _ (Head Timestamp2 st))
  | _ => None
  end.
```

but this is not the case for me sometimes, unfortunately.

---

*Btw.. if it is 4:20 of morning here, can we think it is actually *rather exhaustive* pattern matching?

Comment: Could you please complete the sentence "How to?" It is not clear what you are asking. How to *what*?

Comment: Thank you. it is: How to convince coq that `rest` has type `t_rest` ? (edited the post too)

Answer (score 1):

kind of this works for me

```ml
Definition test4 t_st : stack t_st -> option (stacks t_st) :=
  match t_st as t_st' return stack t_st' -> option (stacks t_st') with
  | Timestamp1 :: (Timestamp1 :: t_rest0 as t_xrest0) =>
      fun '(@Head Timestamp1 ((Timestamp1::t_rest) as t_xrest) x xrest) =>
        let rest : stack t_rest :=
          let '(@Head Timestamp1 t_rest1 y rest2) := xrest in rest2 in
        Some (Build _ (Head Timestamp2 (Head Timestamp2 rest)))
  | _ => fun st => None
  end.
```

thanks to one wise man...